# VS 2017 Community ver and VS 2017 Enterprise debug issue: Found conflicts between different versions

Tags: xamarin.forms

I m having 2 version of VS2017 and a mac with latest macOS. 
I transfer my Xamarin forms App file from VS2017 enterprise to a machine(more than 3 years old but running win10 pro) with VS2017 Community version. When I debug ( with selecting Android project and VS-android-23 X86 tablet as emulator ) this App in VS2017 Community version , I have no compilation error but have these message:

```
Found conflicts between different versions of the same dependent assembly 
that could not be resolved.  
These reference conflicts are listed in the build log when log verbosity is set to detailed.
```

I could not understand this message. I have no problem running the same app in VS2017 Enterprize ver but I have this error message in VS2017 Community ver.

**Update**

```
 Click View > Output --> this will show the error 



1>Starting deploy VisualStudio_android-23_x86_tablet ...
1>Starting emulator VisualStudio_android-23_x86_tablet ...

1>C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Local\Android\ANDROI~1\tools\emulator.EXE -partition-size 512 -no-boot-anim -avd VisualStudio_android-23_x86_tablet -prop monodroid.avdname=VisualStudio_android-23_x86_tablet

1>emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration!

1>Please ensure Intel HAXM is properly installed and usable.

1>CPU acceleration status: Please disable Hyper-V before using the Android Emulator.  Start a command prompt as Administrator, run 'bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off', reboot.

1>Emulator VisualStudio_android-23_x86_tablet cannot be started.
```

Please help.

Comment: try to set the build log verbosity to detail and check what is actually the conflicts